# Sequential scenarios in the same simulation with Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

It's possible multi scenarios in the same simulation?

**Example:**

I have to execute the same test during `2H`, but in each interval time (10min), so I inject different rate user/second (per scenario).

I have tests with:

```
setUp(
      scenario1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).scenario2.inject(2)
  ).protocols(httpProtocolBuilder)
```

but according to results, only executes the last scenario configuration, in example case, for 2 users.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score -1):

so you just want two different scenarios running at the same time?

if so, what you want is...

```
setUp(
  scenario1.inject(
      atOnceUsers(1)
  ).protocols(httpProtocolBuilder),
  scenario2.inject(
      atOnceUsers(1)
  ).protocols(httProtocolBuilder)
)
```